# WMTS access URL for GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wmts, configuration

I have got WMS working through this URL:

http://192.168.5.119:8080/geoserver/sentinel3/wms?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities

But when I try this:

http://192.168.5.119:8080/geoserver/sentinel3/wms?service=WMTS&request=GetCapabilities

I'm getting this:

```
<ows:ExceptionReport version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://192.168.5.119:8080/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
   <ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue" locator="service">
      <ows:ExceptionText>No service: ( WMTS )</ows:ExceptionText>
   </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

This is the Workspace configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct path is not documented anywhere in the GeoServer documents but I managed to guess it. The demo page of your GeoServer has a link to WMTS GetCapabilities:

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetCapabilities

BTW this GetCapabilities URL does not seem to be correct by the WMTS standard because it is lacking the mandatory parameter &SERVICE=WMTS.

The place to add the name of the workspace is after /geoserver/. Try this

http://192.168.5.119:8080/geoserver/sentinel3/gwc/service/wmts?service=WMTS&version=1.0.0&request=GetCapabilities

Answer (score 2):

I was also searching for how to access the WMTS service and found them listed with version numbers on the main page of your Geoserver (http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web) with links (see screenshot).

The WMTS link takes you to something like this:
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?service=WMTS&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities

Then for a specific workspace, you have to add the name between `geoserver/` and `/gwc`, as [user30184](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/424501) wrote:
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/WORKSPACE/gwc/service/wmts?service=WMTS&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities

This is at least for Geoserver version 2.22.1, not sure for any older versions.

[image: Geoserver home page with links to the various services]